# Local machine on network can not resolve Hadoop Name Node Hostname, can be access through ip

Tags: hadoop, hosts

Local machine on network can not resolve Hadoop Name Node Hostname, but can be access through ip address.

on server host files are properly updated.

```
[root@mach1 etc]# more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
#::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.xxx.xxx.46   mach1.com  mach1
10.xxx.xxx.43   mach2.com  mach2
10.xxx.xxx.52   mach3.com  mach3
10.xxx.xxx.53   mach4.com  mach4
```

how to configure this so that any machine can which has access to these ip's can resolve DNS.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If your local machine can resolve this name and other cannot I would suggest creating a DNS server in your network. You can use primary hadoop server for example. Here you can read how to do it http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/domain-name-server.html